# Why is rescaling in latent diffusion done only based on the first batch?

Tags: normalization

In latent diffusion paper, they rescale latent space with std which is estimated across all dimensions (b * c * h * w) but only from the first batch (see below). Why is it not computed on every batch separately? Since std may change across batches and as the encoder model gets trained.

From https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.10752.pdf

[image]